# Why am I gettng this segmentation fault

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, firefox, flash

I need to install flash player to run a web-based program (photo editor) in Firefox. I used these [steps](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-adobe-flash-player-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux/) to do so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
Segmentation fault
```

But I am getting a `Segmentation fault` error. Do you see what is wrong in my command?

Are there any other steps to install this software?

Comment: works for me...

Comment: yikes, flash? are you using pixlr? use photopea. it's much better. flash is so old it's a security risk now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only Firefox where you need to use Flash, installing the `flashplugin-installer` package is sufficient.

Otherwise, the easiest way to enable Canonical Partner is via the *Software & Updates* GUI. Just go to *Other Software* and check Canonical Partner.

There are other ways to install Flash, but the `flashplugin-installer` or `adobe-flashplugin` packages is the best way, since you'll get Flash updates via the ordinary package updates.

More about Flash on Ubuntu [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).